# BibTeX: multiple institutions

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I am citing a report published online jointly by two institutions, using BibTeX. I think the appropriate entry type should be `techreport`. **Is there a standard way to input the institution names in the .bib file in the case of multiple institutions?** For now, I am just adding an "and" between the two institution names in the `institution` field, as in the following example:

```
@techreport{coghlan2008mortality,
    author    = "Coghlan, Benjamin and Bemo, Valerie Nkamgang and Ngoy, Pascal and Stewart, Tony and Mulumba, Flavien and Lewis, Jennifer and Hardy, Colleen and Brennan, Richard",
    title     = "Mortality in the {Democratic Republic of Congo}: An ongoing crisis",
    institution = "International Rescue Committee and Bernet Institute",
    type     = "survey report", 
    year      = "2008",
    month    = "jan",
    note     = "\url{https://www.rescue.org/sites/default/files/document/661/2006-7congomortalitysurvey.pdf} [accessed 2016-7-21]",
}
```

Comment: Probably, or not? Unsure. Maybe. How about giving an example, so we know the bibliographystyle you are using, or if you are using the bibtex system at all. Maybe you are using `biblatex`? Please show a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html).

Comment: @Johannes_B To my knowledge, the way information is input in the .bib file should be independent of the bibliography style? I am using BibTeX. (I indicated that in the title, but it seems I should put it in the body of the question as well.) Sure, I can add an MWE.

Comment: What you put in the bib file is up to you, you can add `authorbirthday=1920-02-29` ... but i guess no bibliographystyle can deal with that. That's the reason why i'm asking for a minimal working example.

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't understand why one should be concerned with adding `authorbirthday=1920-02-29`... not least because, as you pointed out, chances are that no bibliographystyle can deal with that. I am asking specifically about the `institution` field. I change the bibliographystyle I use from time to time, but hopefully I can use the same .bib file. To me that's the main advantage of using BibTeX (compared to just formatting the bibliography on my own), that I don't need to worry about the bibliographystyle changes, which is taken care of by the system.

Comment: @Johannes_B Possibly I didn't make it clear that I was asking about the `institution` field. I've added some clarification.

Comment: I guess most bib-styles for the BibTeX system take the complete content *as is*. For the biblatex system, institution is a literal list.